QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler Implementation
Requirement is to populated 'To' field with specific email addresses when user uses action in feed tab. Problem occurs when user click first 'Reply All' from chatter feed to reply to email message. Then after clicking button latest recipient is loaded to 'To' field. First debug output is null event tough 'To' field on view is populated with latest recipient. Is it possible to overcome this problem?
Implementation:
global class OPERATIONS_EmailPublisherLoader implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler {
    global OPERATIONS_EmailPublisherLoader() {
    }

    global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {
        QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(0);
        EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject();

        if (sendEmailDefaults.getActionName() == 'Case.Chaser_Email') {
            Case c = [SELECT Vendor_NOCs__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()];
            System.debug(emailMessage.ToAddress);
            emailMessage.ToAddress = 'owski@gmail.com';
            if (c.Vendor_NOCs__c != null) {
                emailMessage.ToAddress = c.Vendor_NOCs__c;
            }
            emailMessage.HtmlBody = '#v6a26UR';
            emailMessage.Is_Vendor_Email__c = true;
            emailMessage.CcAddress = ' ';
            System.debug(emailMessage);
        }
    }
}


